# Can kernel modules/configurations fix the Intel 9560 Wi-Fi problem?

Tags: wireless, kernel, intel, iwlwifi

Many questions here asking about Intel 9650 WiFi. I had such a case a month ago as well and the fix in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211877/19-10-thinkpad-l13-intel-9560-wifi-interface-suddenly-disappeared) did work.

But a month later, Wi-Fi does not work even on that kernel version, that I used earlier.

**TL/DR:** The accepted answer quotes another one, and the first sequence of commands did work and make WiFi start without a reboot in `-42` kernel.

## Expanded question

How it happened:

**February**

1. Installed with some unknown kernel version.
2. Ran version `-29`, then updated to `-40`, and Wi-Fi stopped working.
3. Downgraded to `-29` that was still there  as [recommended](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211877/19-10-thinkpad-l13-intel-9560-wifi-interface-suddenly-disappeared) and it worked normally.

**March**

1. Reinstalled the whole system.
2. On first launch, WiFi not working.
3. Checked kernels, and there were `-18` and `-42`. (I conclude that `-18` was in the USB stick, made a month ago, and `-42` was downloaded recently.)

I tried installing version `-29`:

```
sudo apt install linux-image-5.3.0-29-generic \
                 linux-headers-5.3.0-29-generic \
                 linux-headers-5.3.0-29
```

Successfully booted with `-29`, and Wi-Fi still didn`t work.

I'm ignorant of how kernels are configured, but **my theory** is that Ubuntu might somehow configure them on installation via official installer, but not when using `apt`. That's why `-29` worked properly earlier, and did not work yesterday.

I tried `-18`, and on that version, Wi-Fi did work.

Hence the question: is it possible to configure kernel modules to make Intel 9560 Wi-Fi work? If so, how?

## TESTS

In kernel versions `-29` and `-42`, `dmesg | grep iwl` returned nothing. **Moreover, yesterday, I used a smartphone as USB modem to connect to any network. Today it stopped working in -29 & -42 (but did work in -18, so it's not a hardware issue).**

In `-18`:

```
[    2.174871] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.183202] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 43.2.23.17
[    2.183451] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 48.4fa0041f.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.227912] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz, REV=0x354
[    2.372979] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: 98:af:65:d9:76:64
[    2.388138] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[    3.567359] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
```

Modprobe results:

- -42:

  ```
  $ sudo modprobe iwlwifi  
  modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:832 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='iwlwifi'
  modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'iwlwifi': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
  $ sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl
  modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:832 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='iwlwifi'
  modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'iwlwifi': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
  ```
- -18: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi | grep iwl` shows no output.

## Reinstalling modules

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-5.3.0-42-generic linux-modules-5.3.0-42-generic linux-headers-5.3.0-42-generic
```

Succesfully installed.

```
sudo apt purge backports-iwlwifi-dkms
```

Wrote that can't fund such package.

Rebooted under -42, ran

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:832 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='iwlwifi'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'iwlwifi': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

Output is the same as before.

## PARTIAL SUCCESS

As recommended [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2288802&s=642f7ebc93b4c2422f82eeb3858a8c59&p=13330001#post13330001), I tried installing `linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-18-generic` (and same for `-29`, and `-42`). `-18` was already here, but not `extra...-29`, nor `-42`. Rebooted in all 3 versions, here are the results:

- USB network now works in all versions (it did in -18 before thanks to `-extra-`)
- WiFi works in -18 and -29.
- WiFi still not working in -42.

On -42,

- `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` shows nothing.
- `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` shows

  ```
      [    2.901091] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
      [    2.908481] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 43.2.23.17
      [    2.908735] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 48.4fa0041f.0 op_mode iwlmvm
      [    2.953059] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560, REV=0x354
      [    3.978778] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 15 fired.
      [    3.978869] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
      [    3.978874] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000000, count: 92409126
      [    3.978875] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 48.4fa0041f.0
      [    3.978877] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2EF5BBF1 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
      [    3.978877] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x509FEA52 | trm_hw_status0
      [    3.978878] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB79F92B3 | trm_hw_status1
      [    3.978879] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01F784C4 | branchlink2
      [    3.978880] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x830DBEFD | interruptlink1
      [    3.978880] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA9DF0E01 | interruptlink2
      [    3.978881] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x190058B4 | data1
      [    3.978882] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7582BEBE | data2
      [    3.978883] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x916DC435 | data3
      [    3.978883] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDCE030F6 | beacon time
      [    3.978884] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD3D55A0E | tsf low
      [    3.978885] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x9B56DB75 | tsf hi
      [    3.978886] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8AF1A773 | time gp1
      [    3.978886] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x008C95D4 | time gp2
      [    3.978888] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x3EB309E9 | uCode revision type
      [    3.978888] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8EECEB01 | uCode version major
      [    3.978889] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8BC406BA | uCode version minor
      [    3.978890] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0A196B08 | hw version
      [    3.978891] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7186726C | board version
      [    3.978891] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x6874A736 | hcmd
      [    3.978892] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFBDCA85C | isr0
      [    3.978893] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB7564E59 | isr1
      [    3.978893] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF3216FA3 | isr2
      [    3.978894] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x10C6AD0D | isr3
      [    3.978895] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7BA1FB60 | isr4
      [    3.978896] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFD30064F | last cmd Id
      [    3.978896] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x88D90F82 | wait_event
      [    3.978897] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8C5542EA | l2p_control
      [    3.978898] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFDD368FB | l2p_duration
      [    3.978898] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x5EDBF9EF | l2p_mhvalid
      [    3.978899] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x5D9274E9 | l2p_addr_match
      [    3.978900] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB4656752 | lmpm_pmg_sel
      [    3.978901] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x5BBD761D | timestamp
      [    3.978901] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xEB75A2DA | flow_handler
      [    3.978944] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
      [    3.978945] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000000, count: 7
      [    3.978946] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x201013F1 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
      [    3.978947] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
      [    3.978948] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC008CF5C | umac branchlink2
      [    3.978948] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink1
      [    3.978949] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
      [    3.978950] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | umac data1
      [    3.978951] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | umac data2
      [    3.978951] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | umac data3
      [    3.978952] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000030 | umac major
      [    3.978953] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4FA0041F | umac minor
      [    3.978954] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00005D2A | frame pointer
      [    3.978954] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0887F58 | stack pointer
      [    3.978955] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
      [    3.978956] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
      [    3.978980] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
      [    3.978983] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
      [    3.978985] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00260000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
      [    3.978987] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80020006 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
      [    3.978990] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
      [    3.978992] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x1704F891 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
      [    3.978994] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
      [    3.978997] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
      [    3.978999] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
      [    3.979001] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
      [    3.979006] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
      [    3.979010] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000485B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
      [    3.979044] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
      [    3.979073] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x5c9d, CPU2 Status: 0x3
      [    3.979074] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
      [    3.979077] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
      [    3.990800] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
  ```

**PLAYING WITH THE FIRMWARE**

- As suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1218262/5775) doing this:

  sudo rmmod iwlmvm
  sudo rmmod iwlwifi
  sudo cp /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-48.ucode{,.bak}

I have no idea which exact firmware file is used, so guessing blindly. If I understand correctly, chili555 means, Qu-b0  is the newer, and Qu-a0 is the older version, and the older one did work.

So I have Qu-b0 and Qu-c0, and I back up both and copy -b0 to -c0.

```
sudo cp /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-48.ucode /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Quz-c0-jf-b0-48.ucode
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
dmesg | grep iwl

[ 1099.637128] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 43.2.23.17
[ 1099.637276] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 48.4fa0041f.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[ 1099.641714] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560, REV=0x354
[ 1100.656047] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 15 fired.
[ 1100.656153] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[ 1100.656160] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000000, count: 92409100
[ 1100.656164] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 48.4fa0041f.0
[ 1100.656731] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x5c9d, CPU2 Status: 0x3
[ 1100.656735] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
```

The version in the log is the same as before.

Downloading the updated firmware:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.183.2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Still the same, dmesg shows the same firmware version and same errors.

### INTEL FIRMWARE FILES

[Here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html) I downloaded the firmware and unpacked the files into `/lib/firmware`, but dmesg shows the same log as earlier.

## SOLUTION THAT WORKED

The accepted answer quotes another one: [Dell Vostro no WiFi in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218141/dell-vostro-5490-no-wifi-in-ubuntu-18-04), and the first sequence of commands did work and make WiFi start without a reboot in `-42` kernel.

Comment: There is no difference in kernel 5.3.0-29-generic installed from the repositories or from live USB. That theory is very unlikely to be correct.

Comment: Please boot into 5.3.0-42 and run: `dmesg | grep iwl` Next, edit your question to add the result.

Comment: @chili555 added in the end of the qustion. No output in 29, 42, some output in -18.

Comment: Is there output in -42 from: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: @chili555 added them.

Comment: Please check here: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled

Comment: @chili555 oh, that's not my case, I have only Ubuntu on my machine.

I tried firmware from Intel website, still no change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105816/discussion-between-chili555-and-culebron).

Comment: in the chat we figured out that I managed to get some commands wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While booted into -18, please do:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-5.3.0-42-generic linux-modules-5.3.0-42-generic linux-headers-5.3.0-42-generic
sudo apt purge backports-iwlwifi-dkms
```

If the latter is not installed so not removed, that's fine; just proceed.

Reboot into -42 and show us:

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl
```

**EDIT**: Please also do:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-generic
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-42-generic
```

> Failed to run INIT ucode: -110

Please be certain that you have the latest firmware:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.183.2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Next, please undertake the steps here: [Dell Vostro 5490 no WIFI in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218141/dell-vostro-5490-no-wifi-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: Did it, same result. USB network not working either.

Comment: See my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: I actually, got something working, and the output you were looking for.

Comment: Question is: how do I see which firmware file is used, and how do I point at one? (is it on boot or image generation?)